# How to extract a table from text files in Python

Tags: python, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

However, it does not work. Can someone tell me how to do it? I want to finally save this column D in a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have pure text, but you are lucky because your text has some formatting, you can use:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

txt_data = requests.get('https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/n870zs10r/h989r4519/AgriPric-03-30-2017.txt').text
splited_data = txt_data.split('\n')

table_title = 'Prices Received for Field Crops and Fruits - United States: February 2017 with Comparisons'
END_TABLE_LINE = '-------------------------------------------'


def find_no_line_start_table(table_title,splited_data):
    found_no_lines = []
    for index, line in enumerate(splited_data):
        if table_title in line:
            found_no_lines.append(index)

    return found_no_lines

_, table_start = find_no_line_start_table(table_title,splited_data)


def get_start_data_table(table_start, splited_data):
    for index, row in enumerate(splited_data[table_start:]):
        if '(D)' in row:
            return table_start + index

def get_end_table(start_table_data, splited_data ):
    for index, row in enumerate(splited_data[start_table_data:]):
            if END_TABLE_LINE in row:
                return start_table_data + index

def row(l):
    l = l.split()
    number_columns = 5
    if len(l) >= number_columns: 
        data_row = [''] * number_columns
        first_column_done = False

        index = 0
        for w in l:
            if not first_column_done:
                data_row[0] = ' '.join([data_row[0], w])
                if ':' in w:
                        first_column_done = True
            else:
                index += 1
                data_row[index] = w

        return data_row

start_line = get_start_data_table(table_start, splited_data)
end_line = get_end_table(start_line, splited_data)

table = splited_data[start_line : end_line]

def take_table(txt_data):
    comodity = []
    price_2011 = []
    feb_2016 = []
    jan_2017 = []
    feb_2017 = []

    for r in table:
        data_row = row(r)
        if data_row:
            col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5 = data_row
            comodity.append(col_1)
            price_2011.append(col_2)
            feb_2016.append(col_3)
            jan_2017.append(col_4)
            feb_2017.append(col_5)

    table_data = {'comodity': comodity, 'price_2011': price_2011,
                  'feb_2016': feb_2016, 'jan_2017': jan_2017, 'feb_2017': feb_2017}
    return table_data

dict_table = take_table(txt_data)
pd.DataFrame(dict_table)
```

output:

[image]

the table is much longer (43 rows)

you can use either the dict_table or the pandas DataFrame

Comment: Thanks, This helps. I actually wanted to automate this. Since it takes start line and end line as an input. I have to do this for more than 20 years. It will become cumbersome. Is there any alternative to it?

Comment: Just find the line where is the title,  
 thanfind the column by name

Comment: Did that. How do I find the lines using python? Is there something that I should refer to. I am new to Python. That's why asking

Answer (score 1):

It does not work, because you are using an html parser in a file that is not html, but pure text.
You'll need to read the file line by line and determine when you are in the table of interest, than parse the lines and look for the end of the table (effctively the next heading)
It might look like this (not tested):

```
txt_data = requests.get('https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/n870zs10r/h989r4519/AgriPric-03-30-2017.txt').text
parseLines = -1
results = list()
for line in txt_data.splitlines():
    if parseLines > 0:
        try:
            results.append(float(line[70:85]))
        except:
            pass
    if parseLines >0 and line == "next heading":
        parseLines -= 1
    if line == "Prices Received for Field Crops and Fruits - United States: February 2017 with Comparisons": 
        parseLines +=1  # this way the heading in table of contents is skipped
```

Comment: It gives me the error: 
```python
File "<ipython-input-102-8cac1dea96d8>", line 8
    if parseLines >0 and line == "next heading":
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

Comment: @RaghavGoyal: as I mentioned - it's not tested, just an outline